# Action Pattern VS. Controller Pattern: Qual a diferença?

Tags: php, design-pattern, arquitetura-de-software

Estava dando um olhada na arquitetura de um projeto em PHP, e percebi o uso do Action Pattern ao invés do Controller Pattern.

Gostaria de saber a diferença dos Padrões, bem como compreender vantagens e desvatagens de cada um deles.

Segue exemplo de um Action Pattern:

```
abstract class UserAction extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var UserRepository
     */
    protected $userRepository;

    /**
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param UserRepository  $userRepository
     */
    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger, UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        parent::__construct($logger);
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }
}
```

Uma classe que herda esse base abstrata:

```
class ListUsersAction extends UserAction
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function action(): Response
    {
        $users = $this->userRepository->findAll();

        $this->logger->info("Users list was viewed.");

        return $this->respondWithData($users);
    }
}
```

Grato pela ajuda.

Comment: na verdade o _action pattern_ é chamado de [_command pattern_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)